# Jersey web.xml to annotation based configuration along with HK2 binding

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, web.xml, hk2

How to migrate web.xml based configuration to annotation based configuration using Jersey along with HK2 binding.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: Please make sure you are using the same version in the pom files

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**web.xml**      (need to be migrated)

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
>     metadata-complete="false" version="3.1">
>     <servlet>
>         <servlet-name>accRestService</servlet-name>
>         <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
>         <init-param>
>             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
>             <param-value>org.test.ciam.acctmgt</param-value>
>         </init-param>
>         <init-param>
>             <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
>             <param-value>org.bitguiders.ciam.acct.MyAppConfig</param-value>
>         </init-param>
>         <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
>     </servlet>
>     <servlet-mapping>
>         <servlet-name>accountManagementRestService</servlet-name>
>         <url-pattern>/acc/api/*</url-pattern>
>     </servlet-mapping>
> </web-app>
> ```

**MyAppConfig**  (need to be migrated/updated)

> ```
> package org.bitguiders.acc.cfg;
>
> import org.bitguiders.api.exceptions.GenericExceptionMapper;
> import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
> import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
>
>
> public class MyAppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
>     public ApplicationConfig() {
>         register(JacksonFeature.class);
>         register(GenericExceptionMapper.class);
>         register(new DependencyBinder());
>     }
> }
> ```

**ApplicationConfig.java is Replacing both web.xml and MyAppConfig.java with new Java/Annotation-based configuration class.**

> ```
> package org.bitguiders.acc.cfg
>
> import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
>
> import org.bitguiders.acc.api.exceptions.GenericExceptionMapper;
> import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
> import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
>
> @ApplicationPath("acc/api/*")
> public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
>     public ApplicationConfig() {
>         packages("org.bitguiders.acc");
>         register(JacksonFeature.class);
>         register(GenericExceptionMapper.class);
>         register(new DependencyBinder());
>     }
> }
> ```

**HK2 Binding** Sharing this class just to show how HK2 binding is done and what is the purpose of **register(new DependencyBinder())**

```
package org.bitguiders.acc.cfg;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.TypeLiteral;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;


public class DependencyBinder extends AbstractBinder{

private static final String UNSECURED = "unsecured";
private static final String SECURED = "secured";

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(AccountManagementServiceImpl.class).to(AccountManagementService.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bindFactory(AccessTokenStoreFactory.class).proxy(true).proxyForSameScope(false).to(AccessTokenStore.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
    bind(CASLocationServiceImpl.class).to(LocationService.class).named(CAS_LOCATION_SERVICE).in(Singleton.class);
    bindAsContract(LocationServiceFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bindFactory(AccessTokenProviderFactory.class).to(AccessTokenProvider.class).to(new TypeLiteral<Provider<String>>(){}).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(CiamScim2ClientRequireTokenImpl.class).to(CiamScim2Client.class).named(SECURED).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(CiamScim2ClientImpl.class).to(CiamScim2Client.class).named(UNSECURED).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(AccountManagementOptionsServiceImpl.class).to(AccountManagementOptionsService.class).named(SECURED).in(Singleton.class);
    bindAsContract(OptionsApiServiceFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
}
```

}